# Parametrization of real-valued SU(N)

Tags: matrices, unitary-representations

I want to construct a $SU(N)$ matrix $V$, with the following property:

1. All the elements of the first row are given, i.e. $V_{1,j}=a_i$ (with $\sum_i a_i^2=1$)
2. All matrix elements are real, i.e. $V_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}$

> How can I find a matrix $V$ that satifies the criteria? Specifically, how can I find the matrix elements as a function of $a_i$, i.e. $V_{i,j}(a_i)$?

---

**Special case: SU(2)**

$$
   V=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a_1 & a_2 \\
   V_{2,1} & V_{2,2} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

We easily find $V_{2,1}=-a_2$ and $V_{2,2}=a_1$.

---

**Special case: SU(3)**

$$
   V=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
   V_{2,1} & V_{2,2} & V_{2,3} \\
   V_{3,1} & V_{3,2} & V_{3,3} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

Here already I cannot find any feasible way to represent $V_{i,j}$ as a function of $a_1, a_2, a_3$. I have tried to use the generators of SU(3), the [Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices) $\lambda_i$. In particular, $\lambda_2$, $\lambda_5$, $\lambda_7$ are the generators for real-valued SU(3) matrices. However, the resulting equation system involves multiple trigonometric functions for which I cannot solve $V_{i,j}(a_1, a_2, a_3)$.

The matrix $V$ is not unique, I just want any solution.

Comment: Generally your functions $V_{i,j}$ will not be continuous in the variables $a_i$.  This is because if they were continuous, you would be asking for sections of Stiefel bundles, and these often do not exist.   But if you are okay with discontinuous function, yes there are plenty of options. Gram-schmidt is one way to construct such functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is already very interesting. I didn't know that it cannot be done continuously. In my case fortunatly, it is no problem.

Comment: Are there any particular cases that are especially important for your work?  Or do you need the arbitrary $N$ case?   Other than Gram-Schmidt, the holonomy of the tangent bundle also provides a relatively clean solution.

Comment: I would be extremly happy with N=3 already, to get an idea how to construct it, and in particular because I could use the N=3 matrix directly in my project.

Comment: Since you are requiring all the entries to be real, you are really working within $\mathrm{SO}(n)$, so you can easily see that this is impossible for $n=3$, if you want it to be continuous.  The second row would be a nowhere vanishing tangent vector field to the $2$-sphere (the position vector being the first row), and, by a well-known theorem, this is impossible for a continuous tangent vector field.  If you don't require continuity, then, of course, it's easy:  Do it continuously away from a single point on the $2$-sphere (easy) and then define it however you like at that point. (cont....).

Comment: ....(cont from above).  However, for $n=4$ and $n=8$, you can do this.  For example,$$\begin{pmatrix} a_1&a_2&a_3&a_4\\-a_2&a_1&a_4&-a_3\\-a_3&-a_4&a_1&a_2\\-a_4&a_3&-a_2&a_1\end{pmatrix}.$$  The $n=8$ case can be done using the matrix of left multiplication by a unit octonion on the space of octonions, which is a real vector space of dimension 8.  Other than $n=1,2,4,8$, it cannot be done continuously, by a famous theorem of Adams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the comments I made above about continuous solutions, I thought I'd point out a solution that works for all $n$ with only one point of discontinuity, namely
$$
(a_1\ a_2\ \ldots\ a_n) = (1\ 0\ \ldots\ 0).
$$
Away from this point, one can start with the following formulae:

$$
V_{i,1}= V_{1,i} = a_i\qquad\text{and}\qquad
V_{i,j} = \delta_{ij} - \frac{a_ia_j}{(1-a_1)}\quad\text{when}\ 1<i,j\le n
$$
Note that the resulting matrix is both orthgonal *and* symmetric.  However, it has determinant $-1$, so reversing a single row, say, the last one, will give a matrix in $\mathrm{SO}(n)$.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you, i already use it in my codes! How did you find the construction? Did you just use some advanced techniques, or was it obvious for you? (maybe you can add 1-2 sentences, would find it very interesting).

Comment: @MarioKrenn:  Yes, this is the matrix of the orthogonal, linear transformation that exchanges the vector $a= (a_1\ \ldots\ a_n)$ with the vector $n= (1\ 0\ \cdots\ 0)$ and leaves all vectors perpendicular to them fixed.  In other words, it is reflection in the hyperplane orthognal to the difference vector $a-n$.  That's why it has determinant $-1$ and why it isn't defined when $a=n$.

Answer (score 3):

Since you state that already the $3\times 3$ case would be very useful to you:
$$
  V=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \newline
  -\frac{a_2 }{\sqrt{a_1^2 +a_2^2 } } & \frac{a_1 }{\sqrt{a_1^2 +a_2^2 } } & 0 \newline
   -\frac{a_1 a_3 }{\sqrt{a_1^2 +a_2^2 } } & -\frac{a_2 a_3 }{\sqrt{a_1^2 +a_2^2 } } & \sqrt{a_1^2 +a_2^2 }
   \end{array} \right)
$$

Comment: Not continuous (or even well-defined) at $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(0,0,\pm1)$.

Comment: @RobertBryant - As already pointed out by Ryan Budney, one cannot expect a continuous solution in general, so this behavior is not surprising. Of course, supplementing a choice at $a_1 = a_2 =0$ is trivial.

Comment: You are correct, but discontinuities are generally bad for numerical implementations, and your proposed solution is discontinuous at two places rather than the minimal one.  Also, as I point out in my remarks to the question itself, there is a very simple continuous solution when $n=1,2,4,8$.  Also, there is a simpler solution (for all $n$) that has only one point of discontinuity.

Comment: @RobertBryant Thank you - yes, I didn't strive to write down something optimal in terms of continuity. I was mainly reacting to the OP's statement that anything for $N=3$ would be immediately useful and continuity wasn't a concern.

Answer (score 2):

One way to formulate your problem is via [Stiefel bundles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold).

In your case there is the bundle $SU(n) \to S^{2n-1}$ given by taking the first row vector of a special unitary matrix.   You are asking for a way to reverse the process, i.e. if you have a unit row vector you want to complete it to not just a Hermitian basis but one that has determinant one.

The idea is to consider complex mirror reflections $M_p$ in the complex hyperplane orthogonal to vectors $p \in S^{2n-1}$.  Let $q \in S^{2n-1}$ and let $p \in H_q S^{2n-1}$, this  is meant to indicate the hemi-sphere of $S^{2n-1}$ centred at the point $q$.  Then the composite

$$M_q \circ M_p$$

should be essentially the hermitian matrix you are looking for.  Likely it will only be giving you the first column vector the one you want (depending on how you think about matrices, i.e. perhaps you will need to take the transpose).  That vector will be the vector twice as far from p as q is, i.e. take the great circle from p to q, and go twice as far.  That's why there is the discontinuity at the point antipodal to p.

Does this sound reasonable?  Hmm, on second thought, I'm running a bit on autopilot here.  I am not certain if you get every vector in $S^{2n-1}$ via this construction.   In the orthogonal group $O_n \to S^{n-1}$ this construction works fine.  I'll see if this construction can be fixed for $SU(n)$.  But I might need to sleep on it.

Comment: There is an additional requirement that everything must be real, so in fact one deals with $SO_n\to S^{n-1}$